# How to update input from a programmatically set textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, var

I have a textarea that is set with coordinates from a google map. When the user drags the map the coordinates automatically update. I am trying to push every update to an input.

I have the following code (it does not update with the programmatic updates, only when the user changes the text field themselves and clicks off)

```
var newField = document.getElementById("input")

$('#textarea').change(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  newField.value = $this.val();
});
$('#textarea').trigger('change');
```

If there is a better way to do this I am not married to a way or even jquery/js/ajax (if possible/is the best)

I am hoping to essentially mirror the programmatic updates in real time

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to listen to changes in textarea, then update the input accordingly ?Do you want to sync input with content of textarea ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I am a beginner with js/jquery so I would be open to ideas on how to best accomplish it. As long as there is a real time update to the input I am very happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to synchronize the value of input with the value of input . If so, a solution is below which is relying on `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById('input').value = $('#textarea').val();
}, 2);
```

```js
    setInterval(() => {
       
      document.getElementById('input').value = $('#textarea').val();
    }, 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div>
  <h3>Write something in this textarea. It should be reflected in the Input bleow</h3>
  <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="This is textarea..." rows="4" cols="30">
  </textarea>

</div>

<div>
 <input id="input" placeholder="This is input..." type=text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I am intrigued by this, but it is returning undefined for the $('textarea').val() portion. Is there another way of stripping the contents of the textarea out?

Comment: if you can share your HTML so we extract selectors accordingly. Indeed, I assume you have input with ID equals to "#input"  and textarea with ID equals to "#textarea". If you don't have same IDs and you are trying to execute the exact solution , definitely,  it will not work.

Comment: `var textArea = document.getElementById("gmap-macro_map-macrotext0")
var newField = document.getElementById("edit-field-testjs-und-0-value")

setInterval(() => {
   newField.value = $('gmap-macro_map-macrotext0').val();
  }, 2);`

Above are my selectors and your code modified for my selectors

Comment: I got it using `newField.value = document.getElementById("gmap-macro_map-macrotext0").value;` Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @Bestinc !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input` jquery event to bind when the textarea changes its value:

```js
$("textarea").on("input", function(){
  $("input").val($("textarea").val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not appear to work with the pragmatically set textarea